# IndexError: list index out of range : error even after the list isn't

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.4

I get list index out of range error even though it isn't . I am attaching the image of my CSV as well.

```
name=[]
value=[]
readFile=open('CsvMat.csv','r').read()
eachline=readFile.split('\n')


for line in eachline:
    split=line.split(',')
    name.append(split[0])
    value.append(split[1])

pos= arange(len(name))+.5
barh(pos,value,align='center',color='#b8ff5c')
yticks(pos,name)
show()
```

Comment: You probably have an empty line in your input file. Any reason you are not using the `csv` module to read your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

1. You have a line with no commas on it. `split` will be a list with just one element.
2. You have an empty line. `split` is an empty list.

Either way you'd have to guard against that, perhaps with:

```
if len(splits) < 2:
    continue
```

to skip such lines.

You are reading a CSV file; you may want to avoid re-inventing the CSV-reading wheel and use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) here:

```
import csv

names = []
values = []
with open('CsvMat.csv', 'r', newline='') as readfile:
    for name, value, *remainder in csv.reader(readfile):
        names.append(name)
        values.append(float(value))
```

Note that I renamed `name` to `names` and `value` to `values`, to reflect that these are lists. I also converted the values to floating point numbers to make them usable in a plot; if they are integers instead replace `float()` with `int()`.

Comment: Hmm.. I imported module csv in my original piece of code. I tried using the modified code that you provided , and it worked well . My main motto is to create a bar graph. Here is the final code :import csv
from pylab import *

names = []
values = []
with open('CsvMat.csv', 'r', newline='') as readfile:
    for name, value, *remainder in csv.reader(readfile):
        names.append(name)
        values.append(value)

pos= arange(len(names))+.5
barh(pos,values,align='center',color='#b8ff5c')
yticks(pos,names)
show()

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll accept :) . Nevertheless, my motto was to built  a bar graph.. Here is subsequent code:                                                                                
pos= arange(len(names))+.5
print(pos)
barh(pos,values,align='center',color='#072b57')
yticks(pos,names)
show()                                                                                                                            I am getting a new error: TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Comment: @Brilliant: and on what line wuld that be? Perhaps a new question is in order?

Comment: Line 15: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Examples\testing.py", line 15, in <module>
    barh(pos,values,align='center',color='#072b57')

Comment: @Brilliant: that's not the full traceback, just the line where it started; I cannot see from that what causes the exception. Perhaps all values must be integers?

Comment: @Brilliant: I updated the answer a little to convert your values to floats; presumably you they are meant to be numeric?

Comment: so it was the conversion that was required. though all the values in the csv file are integers, not really sure why conversion to float was required.. any thoughts?